# Testing: Parameter input validation

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

In the following code I was wondering if it's okay to adjust the tests that do the name checking. Because once I add the code that checks that the ID cannot be null my first 3 tests fail.

The same goes for the last 3 tests that do the id testing. I have to use 'foo' as a name cause otherwise those tests will fail too. Not sure if that's okay either?

Code to be tested:

```
class Error

class Node
    constructor: (name, id) ->
        if not name?
            throw new Error('Name cannot be null')

        @name = name

        if not id?
            throw new Error('Id cannot be null')

        @id = id

window.Node = Node
```

The spec:

```
node_spec = describe 'Node', () ->

    it 'should have the name foo', () ->
        expect( new Node('foo').name ).toEqual('foo')

    it 'should have the name bar', () ->
        expect( new Node('bar').name ).toEqual('bar')

    it 'should throw an error if the name is null', () ->
        expect( () -> new Node() ).toThrow()

    it 'should have an id of 0', () ->
        expect( new Node('foo', 0).id ).toEqual(0)

    it 'should have an of 1', () ->
        expect( new Node('foo', 1).id ).toEqual(1)

    it 'should throw an error if id is null', () ->
        expect( new Node('foo') ).toThrow()

window.node_spec = node_spec
```

**Update:**
I guess one solution is to have a getter and setter methods for both id and name and test those instead.

Comment: You forgot to mention which testing library you're using. Looks like [Speks](https://github.com/ecavazos/speks)?

Comment: More a StackOverflow question?

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking the same. Do I delete this question and copy paste it to SO?

Comment: No, don't copy paste. Click "flag" and ask a moderator to move it for you.

Comment: A suggestion: You might want to replace the `name?` check with `typeof name is 'string'`, assuming that you want non-string names to be rejected. Likewise, perhaps `typeof id is 'number'` instead of `number?`. Or, if you want to allow non-string names or non-number ids, you should use those in some of your test cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try this again: Right now, you have three tests that are failing. Let's figure out how to address each failure.

### Test #1

```
expect( new Node('foo').name ).toEqual('foo')
```

This is getting an error because `id` is missing. I would keep the test for that error,

```
expect( new Node('foo') ).toThrow()
```

and rewrite test #1 to declare a legit, error-free `Node` instance, just as you do with the `id` test lines:

```
expect( new Node('foo', 1).name ).toEqual('foo')
```

There's nothing wrong with that. Every time you're testing for non-error behavior, you should be instantiating properly; in this case, that means passing a name and an id.

### Test #2

```
expect( new Node('bar').name ).toEqual('bar')
```

This is basically the same as test #1. In fact, I'd say you're actually testing too thoroughly here. The question you should be asking is: Do I have reason to believe that passing `'bar'` as a name instead of `'foo'` will produce a different behavior? I'd say "no."

So I'd either remove the `'bar'` test outright, or replace `'bar'` with `''` (assuming that you want to allow empty strings as names), since a misplaced `or` instead of `?`, or `if name` instead of `if name?`, could cause `''` to behave differently than a string of length > 0.

### Test #3

```
expect( () -> new Node() ).toThrow()
```

This test is failing because `() -> new Node()` defines a function—a function which is never run. I think you mean to write just `new Node()` instead.

### Other thoughts

Looking at the [Speks](https://github.com/ecavazos/speks) docs, it sounds like a preferred style is cut down on repeated instance declaration code using `beforeEach`. Of course, this won't work when you're testing the constructor itself, but you may want to use it for the bulk of your tests in the future.

Here's a rewritten version of your test suite incorporating all of these suggestions and dividing the tests into three types: Those where an exception is created, those where normal behavior is expected, and those where the object *should* behave properly but is an edge case:

```
node_spec = describe 'Node', () ->

  # exception tests
  it 'should throw an error if there are no arguments', () ->
      expect( new Node() ).toThrow()

  it 'should throw an error if there is only one argument', () ->
      expect( new Node('foo') ).toThrow()

  # normal tests
  node = new Node('foo', 1)

  it 'should have an id of 1', () ->
      expect( node.id ).toEqual(1)

  it 'should have the name foo', () ->
      expect( node.name ).toEqual('foo')

  # slightly unusual case of id = 0, name = '' (convertible to false)
  node = new Node('', 0)

  it 'should have an id of 0', () ->
      expect( node.id ).toEqual(0)

  it 'should have an empty string as its name', () ->
      expect( node.name ).toEqual('')
```

Comment: This solves my problem thanks. I have one comment though. If I read about TDD they say you should write as little code to make your test pass. So to make a test like expect( (new Node('foo')).name )toEqual('foo') pass you can just hardcode the string 'foo' to be returned. That's why there is a test for 'bar'. I was using this as a starting point: http://blog.extracheese.org/2009/11/how_i_started_tdd.html

Comment: Ah, well if you're writing the spec first, then yes, I could see the advantage of the extra test. :)

Answer (score 3):

**Edited after matyr's comment below:** I'd initially believed that this was due to the quirkiness of the `new` operator, since several of the tests use the syntax `new Foo().bar`. However, `new` behaves as Pickels had expected in those circumstances. So although this answer is *not* the solution to the stated problem, here's a review for posterity's sake:

When you write

```
new A().B
```

you're referencing the `B` property of a new `A` instance.

But if you write

```
new A.B()
```

(or just `new A.B`—CoffeeScript implicitly adds parentheses at the end of the `new` target if they're absent) then you're creating a new instance of `A.B`. This gets pretty confusing—what's `new A().B()`?—because the `new` operator has its own special precedence rules. So, I recommend using parentheses to clarify such code, e.g.

```
(new A).B
new (A.B)
```

There was [discussion here](http://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/619) about trying to make this behavior more intuitive in CoffeeScript, but after an energetic effort, it was determined that "the cure was worse than the disease."

Comment: Wow, I actually didn't know about this.

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely confusing to us humans, though it makes total sense if you're a compiler—everything after `new` is evaluated as a single expression. :) Did that fix your original problem?

Comment: `new Node('foo').name` equals `(new Node('foo')).name`, not `new (Node('foo').name)`. Reread #619?

Comment: Sorry about that—I had a nasty feeling that there was an error in my post, but you beat me to correcting it. Revising...